# .Net Regular Expression to get parenthetical text at end of <p> tags

Tags: .net, wpf, regex, vb.net

I have a simple pattern I am trying to match, any characters captured between parenthesis at the end of an HTML paragraph.   I am running into trouble any time there is additional parentheticals in that paragraph:

i.e.

If the input string is "..... (321)</p>" i want to get the value (321)

However, if the paragraph has this text:  "... (123) (321)</p>" my regex is returning 
"(123) (321)"  (everything between the opening "(" and closing ")"

I am using the regex pattern "\s(.+)</p>"

How can I grab the correct value (using VB.NET)

This is what I'm doing so far:

```
    Dim reg As New Regex("\s\(.+\)</P>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim matchC As MatchCollection = reg.Matches(su.Question)
    If matchC.Count > 0 Then
        Dim lastMatch As Match = matchC(matchC.Count - 1)
        Dim DesiredValue As String = lastMatch.Value
    End If
```

Comment: **DO NOT PARSE HTML USING Regular Expressions!** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2):

Just change the expression to non-greedy and reverse the match order:

```
Dim reg As New Regex("\s\(.+?\)</P>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
```

Or make it match only one closing parenthesis:

```
"\s\([^)]+\)</P>"
```

Or make it match only numbers inside your pharentesis:

```
"\s\(\d+\)</P>"
```

*Edit: in order to make the non-greedy sample to work, you'll need to set the RightToLeft flag on the `Regex` object*

Comment: I made that change, but the parsing through the text: "....(123) (321)</p>"  still returns "(123) (321)</p>"

Comment: .. i just want it to return "(321)</p>"

Comment: Check again my suggestions, I edited a little bit. The non-greedy method still works, but need an extra flag on RegexOptions.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim reg As New Regex("\s\(\d+\)</P>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Your stumbling block was the insufficient specificity of the `.` (it matches all characters, including parentheses) and the greediness of the `+` (it matches as much as possible).

Just be more specific (`\d+`) or less greedy (`.+?`).

Comment: "Less greedy" won't work; RE engines always try to start matching as soon as possible. Being more specific is the correct approach.

Comment: I just edited my answer with non-greedy suggestion, it actually works, but you'll have to set the Regex engine to work backwards (the RegexOptions.RightToLeft on .NET will do this)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Look Ahead **(?= )** to anchor the pattern. That gives a hint to the parser of where the data should stop, be anchored to. Here is an example which gets the previous ( ) data from the p tag anchor point:

```
(?:\()([^)]+)(?:\))(?=</[pP]>)


(?:\()        - Match but don't capture a (
([^)]+)       - Get all the data until a ) is hit. [^ ] is the not set
(?:\))        - Match but don't capture the )  
(?=</[pP]>)  - Look Ahead Match but don't capture a suffix of </p or P >
```

HTH